# Generating JSX from JHipster

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jsx, jhipster

Currently, jhipster output app uses typescript for react client.

Is that possible to generate the client app with jsx instead of tsx ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only if you want to write your own JHipster blueprint https://www.jhipster.tech/modules/creating-a-blueprint/ this is not a trivial task